# import Event Types from React (TypeScript)

Tags: reactjs, import, typescript, material-ui

How to import Event Types from React?

For an example how to import KeyboardEvent so it can be used for onKeyDown callback type annotation?

I have browsed Material-ui .d.ts file and found that in that file EventTypes are used as defined in React

```
onKeyDown?: React.KeyboardEventHandler;
```

And in React .d.ts

```
type KeyboardEventHandler = EventHandler<KeyboardEvent>;
```

But I can't find a way to use import them ...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It's works fine for me:

```
handleKeyPress (event: React.KeyboardEvent): any {
}
```

And I use material-ui too

Answer (score 10):

Add `KeyboardEvent` to your react import statement. Then, in your handler you can use the KeyboardEvent type. If you don't specify it in the import statement, you will use ES5 declaration of KeyBoardEvent, which won't compile with your react project.

```
import React, { Component, KeyboardEvent } from "react";

export class MyInput extends Component{
...

  handleKeyDown(e: KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    console.log(e);
    // Do something here
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <input onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown.bind(this}/>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you receive error "`KeyboardEvent requires type argument`" with React 16.1+ you can do:

```
private onKeyDown = (event: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
   ... 
}
```

where the generic arg is the type of your element.

Comment: you can do that, but I wouldn't recommend it, the typescript docs say unless you are migrating a JS project to typescript you shouldn't use the `any` type: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#:~:text=any,every%20usage%20of%20the%20variable.

Comment: updated my answer accordingly